# increment a value pulled from a file

Tags: shell, variable, arithmetic

I have a cron that I am writing that will repeat every hour, and I need a simple way to pass a counter from the last run to the next run.

My plan was to add the number to a file at the end, and then call it back at the beginning, e.g.

At end of the first cron run:

```
INC_COUNT=1
echo $INC_COUNT > inc_counter.txt
```

Then at the start of the second run:

```
INC_COUNT_FILE="inc_counter.txt"
OLD_INC_COUNTER=$(cat "$INC_COUNT_FILE")
```

So far so good, but now I need to increment that number.
I tried:

```
NEW_INC_COUNTER="$OLD_INC_COUNTER"+1
NEW_INC_COUNTER="$OLD_INC_COUNTER+1"
```

neither of which worked. What is the best way to increment this number?

Comment: Your `NEW_INC_COUNTER` is `1+1` string. If you want to [add](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) integer to variable, you can write it this way: `NEW_INC_COUNTER=$((OLD_INC_COUNTER+1))`. BTW: `i++` equivalent from C language in bash is `$((i++))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following methods will work:

1. `NEW_INC_COUNTER=$((OLD_INC_Counter+1))`
2. `((NEW_INC_COUNTER = OLD_INC_Counter+1))`
3. `((OLD_INC_Counter+=1))`
4. `((OLD_INC_Counter++))`
5. `let "NEW_INC_COUNTER = OLD_INC_Counter+1"`
6. `let "OLD_INC_Counter+=1"`
7. `let "OLD_INC_Counter++"`

**Good luck!**

Comment: Also, `NEW_INC_COUNTER=$(expr "$OLD_INC_Counter" + 1)`.  The spaces before and after the `+` are required.  Note, that, unlike the above, this will work if you fall into a time warp and come out in the 1980s.  (Except, strictly speaking, you would need to use `NEW_INC_COUNTER=\`expr "$OLD_INC_Counter" + 1\``; the `$(…)` syntax wasn't invented until a few years later.)  (Oh, there are also solutions featuring `echo … | bc` and `echo … | dc`.)

Comment: cheers for that, they worked perfectly,

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $( (( $(cat inc_counter.txt) + 1 )) ) > inc_counter.txt
```